# What is the best way to distribute postgreSQL windows binaries with our own applications?

Tags: postgresql

My application uses **postgreSQL Server** for database operations. Am looking for a way to distribute **postgreSQL windows binaries** during installation of my application. As of my research i found we can distribute postgreSQL installer setup and make **unattended installation** on it. Is this a better way to do?.
Let me know the possible way to make out this work. Thanks.

Comment: You could include the binaries from the [zip archive](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name From your comment i am assuming that distributing the binaries is better way rather than making **unattended installation** on postgreSQL installer. Am i right?